# ¿Existe un comando para deshacer la ultima acción en Git?

Tags: git

¿Hay algún comando o combinación que permita deshacer de forma general alguna acción reciente, más allá de las propias para acciones concretas? Es decir alguna forma de devolver el repositorio a un estado anterior, ramas, commits, etc... aun después de eliminar, fusionar, etc.

> Editado:

Estuve haciendo un poco de todo, crear/eliminar/fusionar/renombrar ramas, hacer/deshacer commits, en local y remoto, y resolver algunos problemas... se echa en falta algún comando general para deshacer cosas difíciles de resolver.

Comment: Qué has investigado y probado? Qué errores o problemas concretos tuviste haciendolo?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: La respuesta corta es SI
Pero Depende de la acción!
Hiciste `git add` o `git commit` o `git push`?
Cada una tendrá una respuesta, aunque todas están en la documentación de git

Comment: otro comando. si editastes y no quieres subirlo usa el comando `git checkout tuarchivo` de lo deveolvera al ultimo commit o incluso un `git fetch`

Answer (score 5):

puedes probar con:

```
git reset --hard {commit_id}
```

con esto tu indice de la rama baja (o sube) al commit indicado.

Al mover este indice, si luego quieres sobreeescribr esos cambios, no puedes directamente (porque en el origin el indice esta en la rama final), asi que entonces puedes forzar la subida con:

```
git push origin --force
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es moverte por ramas, yo ahora estoy experimentando con `git stash` . Aquí te dejo la documentación: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash